# Understanding the binary format of QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt, binary-data

I am trying to decode a binary file that was written by CloudCompare using a small Kotlin tool I am writing. I figured that since CloudCompare is open source, this should be fairly simple, but I am struggling with one particular issue.

I am trying to decode the name of a CloudCompare entity and CloudCompare uses the following C++ code to decode it:

```
// Header file
QString m_name;

// Source file
bool ccObject::fromFile(QFile& in, short dataVersion, int flags, LoadedIDMap& oldToNewIDMap)
{
    // ...

    //name
    if (dataVersion < 22) //old style
    {
        // ...
    }
    else //(dataVersion>=22)
    {
        QDataStream inStream(&in);
        inStream >> m_name;
    }

    // ...
}
```

So, in essence, CloudCompare wraps the binary input stream in `QDataStream` and asks `QDataStream` to decode a `QString`. The [documentation of the binary format](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/datastreamformat.html) that `QDataStream` uses specifies, that `QString`s are encoded with their length encoded as a `quint32` followed by the string encoded in UTF-16. However, the data that I am trying to decode does not seem to match up with that. Here's the data in question:

[image: Binary data to be decoded]

When trying to decode the name, the seek position of the input stream is at `0x0010`. If I follow the docs, I would parse the following for bytes (`0x77 0x04 0x00 0x00`) with big-endian byte order to an unsigned int (which evaluates to `1996750848`) and expect the actual UTF-16 string to start at offset `0x0014`). But as you can see, the string only starts at offset 0x0018 and and if you decode the bytes from 0x0014 to 0x0017, they indeed decode to `14`, the length of the UTF-16 string in bytes. Hence, there seem to be 4 bytes from offset `0x0010` to `0x0013`  which I don't understand the purpose of.

My first guess is that `QDataStream` encodes some header information there, but I couldn't find any documentation on what that could be. Hence, my question boils down to what these four bytes mean and whether I need to parse them at all or if skipping them is possible without any side-issues.

Comment: No, the QDataStream source code does not do anything special inbetween the creation of the object and the `operator>>` call. Is the size of your file close to 0x477 (1143 bytes), by any chance? It is not uncommon to record total file or chunk size at the start of the file, but this would be CloudCompare's doing, not QDataStream's.

Comment: Well, I also read in the docs of `QDataStream` that it supports versioning, where would it store that if not in some sort of header? Also, I am pretty sure that CloudCompare doesn't store anything there itself as I stared at its source code for a long while :)

Comment: Also, the total size of the file is 0x91AB, so that rules that out

Comment: QT does not store anything. The documentation tells you to put metadata like that in your code or before the actual QDataStream.

Comment: Well, but the documentation also states: "QDataStream's binary format has evolved since Qt 1.0, and is likely to continue evolving to reflect changes done in Qt. When inputting or outputting complex types, it's very important to make sure that the same version of the stream." ([source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdatastream.html#versioning))

Comment: See my answer. You missed to account for the call to read a unique ID in `ccObject::fromFile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracing through the CloudCompare source code tells me the following about the file format:

- 0x00+3 `43 43 42` (CCB) specify that a `BinFilter` should be used to read
- 0x03+1 `32` are "load flags", whatever those may be.
- 0x04+4 `34 00 00 00` is the file version. 0x34 = 52. The latest version is 54 apparently.
- 0x08+8 `01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` is the class ID of the object being read. 0x1 is a "HObject".
- Control transfers to `ccHObject::fromFile`. First thing it does is call `ccHObject::fromFileNoChildren`, which calls `ccObject::fromFile`.
- 0x10+4 `77 04 00 00` is the "unique ID of this object", as of data version 20. **This is the bit you overlooked**.
- 0x14 is the start of a serialized QString, as you showed in your question.

Comment: Actually, I found the issue. I read the class id as a 32 bit int while I should have read it as a 64bit long. By accident, this still resulted in the correct class id, but also in 4 bytes not being read, which is how I got confused.

Comment: For added fun, it looks like CloudCompare's "native" format assumes a little-endian computer but QDataStream defaults to big-endian. Guess it is too late to change that now...